# Create DetailsView from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to Asp.net and have looked around for how to do this, but haven't been able to find it.

I would like to create a detailsview entirely from codebehind.  This is because I need certain fields to load based on the user's permissions.  Also, I would like the ability to edit the detailsview to be only accessible to certain users.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you using Webforms or MVC? If you're not using MVC, start.

Comment: Why do you have to create it in codebehind? Why not just create it normaly and hide it or show it based on users permission, and then just add controls dynamically to it.

Comment: @Daniel Mann I'm using webforms. I figured that would best since I'm still learning before going onto MVC. Is that not correct? Is MVC better fr this type of thing?

Comment: @Hanlet Escaño I just figured it had to be done in codebehind. I'm still new to .net so I didnt know there were other options. Do you have an example what you're referring to?

Comment: @Cineno28 MVC is a more generic pattern that's used in many languages. It also provides for better separation of concerns and is more testable. I recommend MVC over Webforms to anyone who is just starting out with web development with C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a  very basic implementatation of DetailsView programmatically. This will get you started.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DetailsView dv = new DetailsView();
        dv.ID = "MyDv";
        dv.DataSource = GetDataSet(); // returns a dataset filled using Select Query

        TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
        tf.ItemTemplate = new AddTemplateToDetailsView(ListItemType.Item);

        dv.Fields.Add(tf);

        dv.DataBind();
        placeholder1.Controls.Add(dv);

    }
```

Class file code to add TemlplateField. `<asp:TemplateField>`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;

public class AddTemplateToDetailsView : ITemplate
{
   private ListItemType _ListItemType;

    public AddTemplateToDetailsView(ListItemType listItemType)
    {
       _ListItemType = listItemType;
    }
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        if (_ListItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            Label lblID = new Label();
            lblID.DataBinding += new EventHandler(lblID_DataBinding);
            container.Controls.Add(lblID);    
        }    
    }    
    void lblID_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        Label lblID = (Label)sender;
        DetailsView container = (DetailsView)lblID.NamingContainer;
        lblID.Text = ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)["CustomerID"].ToString();
    }

}
```

In case you also need to add `InsertItemTemplate` OR `EditItemTemplate`, You can create UserControls for the same and add those in `Page_Init()` as below. The UserControl must Inherit `ITemplate` .

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.DetailsView1.EditItemTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("UserControlEdit.ascx");
this.DetailsView1.InsertItemTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("UserControlInsert.ascx");
}
```

Read [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.loadtemplate.aspx) .

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This seems to be what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

To complete R.C. answer:
In dataBinding method, if datasource is not a DataRowView, you may use:

```
lblID.Text = DataBinder.Eval(dv.DataItem,"CustomerID").ToString();
```

It works for me.
I found it several times on this forum.